# Angularjs: $resource chaning with a $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource, angular-http

How could I compare the result of these different calls? The url, and the fruit list stored in a different json file, and I would compare them before I send them as a promise. They should wait each other, and fulfilled in a common promise.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $resource) {
    var list = {};
    $http.get('images.json').then(function(response) {
      response.data.objects.forEach(function(images) {
        list[images.id] = images.url;
      });
    });
    $resource('fruits.json').get().$promise.then(function(response) {
      var list = {
        1: 'badUrlExampleForApple',
        2: 'badUrlExampleForOrange',
        3: 'badUrlExampleForPineapple'
      }
      response.objects.forEach(function(product) {
        if (list[product.id]) {
          console.log(product.name + ': ' + list[product.id]);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

I know it's a little bit feird, but I have to do it in this manner.

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ICwvYI?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `$q.all` to get a promise whose `.then` unwraps both of them:

```
var images = $http.get('images.json');
var fruits = $resource('fruits.json').get().$promise;

$q.all([images,fruits]).then(function(results){
    var images = results[0];
    var fruits = results[1];
    // access to both here, you can compare anything you want
});
```

The guide for `$q.all` says:

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

In other promise libraries like Bluebird and in ES6 promises, thatr functionality would probably be `Promise.all`, in the original Q it's `Q.all` .